# Как сделать динамическую выборку из бд в файле php?

Tags: php

Допустим на сайте интернет магазина есть 3 ссылки на один и тот же php файл, пусть это будет: одежда для женщин, одежда для мужчин, одежда для детей. В php файле простая пагинация галереи. Как сделать так чтобы в зависимости от ссылки, выдавался   соответствующий результат? То есть по нажатию на "одежда для женщин" в галерее были картинки из бд с платьями и т.д.

Answer (score 2):

К ссылкам добавьте, к примеру, GET параметры:

```
<a href="/shop.php?filter=1">для женщин</a>
<a href="/shop.php?filter=2">для мужчин</a>
<a href="/shop.php?filter=3">для детей</a>
```

В shop.php проверяйте значение в ссылке и корректируйте запрос к базе

```
<?
if(isset($_GET['filter'])) { 
  if($_GET['filter'] == 1) $add = " WHERE `section` = 'men'";
  elseif($_GET['filter'] == 2) $add = " WHERE `section` = 'women'";
  elseif($_GET['filter'] == 3) $add = " WHERE `section` = 'children'";
} 

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `clothes`".$add;
 ?>
```

В базе, соответственно, нужно хранить информацию о типе одежды для каждой строки.